# LibreOffice fixed table size

Tags: libreoffice

I'm trying to make a table which has the exact size of the printing area of my paper. But it seems I can't use specific measurements to make it that. Also, if I delete a row, I'd like it to change the height of every row accordingly so the total height stays the same.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

For the table width you may select the table and then choose *Table -> Table Properties*, select *Alignment = Manual* and define the exact size of the printing paper.

The automatic height adjustment after a row deletion is not possible (at least at my knowledge)